# Passing & symbol in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert an email link using jquery, but if the email body has a `&` in it, it will not work.

```
$('#em_button').html('<a href="mailto:?subject=A Photo: ' + js_images[getImg].title + '&body=I thought you would like this photo: ' + thisPage + '?id=' + getGall + '&img=' + js_images[getImg].filename + '"><img src="' + homeUrl + '/' + tUrl + '/img/email.png" title="Email this photo" /></a>');
```

The part that is breaking it is `&img=`. I've tried using `&amp;` but that didnt work either. Any suggestions?

Note: If there is no `&`, everything works fine.

Comment: "Will not work" means nothing. What are you expecting to get? What are you getting?

Comment: The link outputted stops where the `&` is in the link

Comment: How about an example of your input and output?

Comment: Why do you have two question marks in your URL? And it should be $amp; when inserting this into HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, hope it works

```
'%26img='
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you have a second `?` in your query string.

You should substitute the second `?` with `&amp;`. Also all your `&` should be written as `&amp;`

```
$('#em_button').html('<a href="mailto:?subject=A Photo: ' + js_images[getImg].title + '&amp;body=I thought you would like this photo: ' + thisPage + '&amp;id=' + getGall + '&amp;img=' + js_images[getImg].filename + '"><img src="' + homeUrl + '/' + tUrl + '/img/email.png" title="Email this photo" /></a>');
```

Comment: No, that didnt do anything. Plus if I only have one GET variable, using a ? it works.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what is in `js_images[getImg]`, it's hard to say what is going wrong.

One thing to keep in mind is that you should always encode components before creating a URL. For example:

```
var x = encodeURIComponent(js_images[getImg].title)
$('#em_button').html('<a href="mailto:?subject=A Photo: '+ x +'&body...')
```

Furthermore, if you're creating something like a link, you might want to make things clearer by writing it as follows:

```
var url = 'mailto:subject=A Photo: ' + encodeURIComponent(js_images[getImg].title) +
    '&body=I thought you would like this photo: ' + encodeURIComponent(thisPage) +
    '&id=' + encodeURIComponent(getGall) +
    '&img=' + encodeURIComponent(js_images[getImg].filename);

var src = encodeURIComponent(homeUrl) + '/' +
    encodeURIComponent(tUrl) + '/img/email.png'

var $a = $('<a/>', {
    href: url
});

var $img = $('<img/>', {
    src: src,
    title: 'Email this photo'
});

$a.append($img);
$('#em_button').html($a);

$('#em_button').html('<a href="mailto:?subject=A Photo: ' + js_images[getImg].title + '&body=I thought you would like this photo: ' + thisPage + '?id=' + getGall + '&img=' + js_images[getImg].filename + '"><img src="' + homeUrl + '/' + tUrl + '/img/email.png" title="Email this photo" /></a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

use `+encodeURIComponent('&')+`

Answer (score 0):

If you just append the URL parameters and the body text into one string, the `&` from inside the body text would be parsed as URL argument. In PHP i would use `urlencode` to encode occurrences of such characters into `%xx`-values.

Looking at the answer of Константин Рекунов, I would assume you could use `encodeURIComponent` to encode the body contents.

```
encodeURIComponent( thisPage + '?id=' + getGall + '&img=' + js_images[getImg].filename )
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

You could avoid that problem by using URL rewriting on your server for the image files.

Instead of:

```
thisPage + '?id=' + getGall + '&img=' + js_images[getImg].filename
```

…it might be:

```
thisPage + '/' + getGall + '/img/' + js_images[getImg].filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "&" try using `&amp;`